# Adding image to contentpane in window application

Tags: java, image, swing

How can i add, set visible and bounts, my "images/name.jpg" into my ContentPane window container?

```
public class WindowName extends JFrame
{
    public WindowName()
    {
        JFrame Window = new JFrame(); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("...");
        setSize(700, 600);  
        setVisible(true);
        Container powZawartosci = getContentPane();
        powZawartosci.setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be a background?  BTW 1) `setSize(700, 600);` Don't do that,  instead set the preferred size of the children and pack the frame. 2) `powZawartosci.setLayout(null);` a) Use English in examples posted to sites that are primarily conducted in English.  b) **Use layouts.**

Answer (score 3):

Just add a JLabel to the content pane. See [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).